# Hide cursor on Winforms Webbrowser hosted in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor, webbrowser-control, hide

I'm using a WinForms Webbrowser inside a WPF application, 
Because of the Webbrowser is in a touch screen I need to hide the mouse cursor but don't know how to it with this element architecture !
I'm using WinForms Webbrowser instead of WPF one to get access to the ScriptErrorsSuppressed property.

Comment: You're in a WPF application so why can't you just set the Cursor property of the whole application or that control to None or No?

Comment: Already tried, but it doesn't it.